# Why does deletion of rows from one table work, but not from another?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I am trying to delete rows from tables. The code in the first program succeeds in deleting a row. The code in the second, similar program deletes zero rows.

However, when issuing the same  delete command from the SQL command line tool, it reports one row being deleted.

First program:

```
package oracle;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class JDBCPreparedStatementInsertExample {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER      = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION  = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    private static final String DB_USER        = "system";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD    = "datta123";

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try {

            insertRecordIntoTable();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    private static void insertRecordIntoTable() throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;


        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            System.out.println("oracle database is connected:\n");
            String deleteSQL = "DELETE DBUSER WHERE username = ?";
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteSQL);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Avi");
            // execute delete SQL stetement
            int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("success:"+i);

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {

                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {

                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {

        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try {

            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        try {

            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            return dbConnection;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        return dbConnection;
     }
}
```

output:

```
oracle database is connected:
success:1
```

Second program:

```
package oracle;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class JDBCPreparedStatementInsertExample {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER     = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    private static final String DB_USER       = "system";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD   = "datta123";

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try {

            insertRecordIntoTable();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    private static void insertRecordIntoTable() throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;


        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            System.out.println("oracle database is connected:\n");
            String deleteSQL = "DELETE admin WHERE name = ?";
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteSQL);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "datta");
            // execute delete SQL stetement
            int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("success:"+i);

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {

        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try {

            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        try {

            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            return dbConnection;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        return dbConnection;
    }
}
```

output:

```
oracle database is connected:
success:0
```

But from the command line tool, the same query is executed successfully:

```
SQL> delete admin where name='datta';

1 row deleted.
```

Comment: Note: please do not use shortened words like "wrk" and "frm". StackOverflow is not a mobile chat. Instead, create a concise title and put the full text of your question inside the question body, for clarity and readability.

Comment: What is the data type of `name` in `admin`?  Any chance it is a `char` rather than a `varchar2`?  Not that it likely has anything to do with this specific problem, but don't use the `system` (or `sys`) user for development.  That's a reserved user and schema that you should never create objects in.  Create a new schema for your application and create your objects there.

Comment: Had the admin record been added in the command line client session without committing it, perhaps?

Comment: Many Thanks Alex Poole .it was issue of commit and  succesfully runs second program.